# ROS Answers SE migration: Odometer Code

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,

I'm implementing Odometer in the navigation stack using this:

http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom

What I understood is that in order to make this code really work on my robot then i'll have to change some stuff.
for example:

16   double vx = 0.1;

17   double vy = -0.1;

18   double vth = 0.1;

I changed those values manually because i dont have a driver. I got help from this:

[http://www.geology.smu.edu/~dpa-www/robots/doc/odometry.txt](http://www.geology.smu.edu/%7Edpa-www/robots/doc/odometry.txt)

However, my question is what else should i change?

thank you,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206500/odometer-code/) by [maha](https://answers.ros.org/users/21965/maha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2015-04-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is just dummy code showing how to fill such messages. What you have to change for your robot depends on your robot's data. There is no general answer for that.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [maha](https://answers.ros.org/users/21965/maha/) on 2015-04-07**:
can you explain further or provide a source explaining the code.. i dont understand what's in the website. it is not enough.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-04-08**:
Odometry only makes sense, when it comes to a robot. So, at least the velocity values or pose estimates needs to be robot data. Unless you have that it doesn't make sense to publish odometry. If you want more detailed information, you'll have to provide what data you can get out of your robot.

**Comment by [maha](https://answers.ros.org/users/21965/maha/) on 2015-04-08**:
i can get anything out of my robot.. i already provided the velocities,, how can i get the pose estimates?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-04-08**:
In this case the code should already work. You only need to continuously update these. It integrates velocities to get pose estimates in ll 31-34. If you have direct pose estimates, e.g., from encoders your code also use these.